# What is a "<refinement>" type gotten through a TypeTag?

Tags: scala, reflection, implicits

I have a method:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag,typeOf}

def print[T:TypeTag] = println(typeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toString)
```

Most of the time, `print[MyClass]` prints `MyClass` when invoked, but sometimes, it prints `<refinement>`?

I am working on a fairly complex system (multiple interconnecting jars, 100K lines of code), and I cannot seem to identify what determines if it is the one behaviour or the other. But if I knew what `<refinement>` means, or what triggers that, maybe I could?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refinements could be explained as anonymous class type. E.g.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag,typeOf}

def print[T:TypeTag] = println(typeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toString)

class C
trait T

print[C with T]

type A = C with T

print[A]
```

Output will be `<refinement>` in both cases.